# How to persist the change in JAXB object to its corresponding XML file?

Tags: java, jaxb

I am new to JAXB.
Server is sending a few xmls which need to be replaced in the client. My requirement is to back up some element's data from previous XML tables' JAXB objects and update into the new xmls' object once they are successfully replaced in the client.
I don't have problem in backing up the data but while updating the data, only JAXB object is updated while I need to persist in the corresponding XMLs too. Is there any way JAXB supports to accomplish this?

Comment: Marshal the Java object to the output stream (or file, string, whatever), using the [`Marshaller`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html)

Comment: Can u show what u have till now